# How to call TortoiseSVN Explorer context menu?

Tags: windows-explorer, tortoise-svn, shell-extensions

I have none if rightclick. Where it should be?

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

Permission problem is not the reason.

Comment: Reinstall the application and click the option to add the context menu enteries.

Comment: Where is this option? I have all setup screenshots and see none.

Comment: What do you mean you have all setup screenshots?

Comment: @Ramhound I mean I took screenshots of all windows during install and see them in front of my eyes now and I see none where option you ay presented.

Comment: http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#nomenus the solution posted there will work, sounds like, you didn't install the 64-bit process.

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

[image]

After install you may need to perform a reboot to have them appear.

If that doesn't help, you may want to attempt a full uninstall and reinstall of TortoiseSVN.

Other things it could be: registry permission problem, conflict with other context menu entries, corrupted files/context menu entries, etc.

Perhaps check out these related StackOverflow.com links for some ideas on how to fix it:

- [SVN commands does not appear in context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857564/svn-commands-does-not-appear-in-context-menu)
- [[Tortoise SVN]: No context menu in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605278/tortoise-svn-no-context-menu-in-windows-7)
- [TortoiseSVN does not show context menu on files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558854/tortoisesvn-does-not-show-context-menu-on-files)

Answer (score 0):

You might be checked "Hide Menus for unversioned path" in Context Menu inside SVN settings. Uncheck the box and check or Press Shift + right click so that the context menu will appear.